# Laravel HTML <select>

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I just want to achieve a simple task.

My .blade.php file has a select box for roles with values:

```
<p>Role:</p>
<div class="form-group">
    <select name="role_id" id="role_id">
        <option value="1">Admin</option>
        <option value="2" selected="selected">User</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

And my request handler is simple:

```
 $user = User::create([
     'name' => $request['name'],
     'surname' => $request['surname'],
     'email' => $request['email'],
     'password' => Hash::make($request['password']),
     'role_id' => $request['role_id'],
 ]);
```

role_id is integer column

But I get error: `Field 'role_id' doesn't have a default value.`

Like I was not even passing the value? Do I miss something?

What I tried: I tried to google it, but everyone seems to be working with some Laravel selection box, which is just too overwhelming for me at the moment. I want to keep it simple with HTML.

Comment: Hi, before `User::create`, you can try putting the code `dd($request);` to check if `role_id` is present.

Comment: If you `dd($request->all());` what do you  see? If `role_id` is not set, then its probably not send to the back end. Can you show us your whole HTML form?

Comment: did you put role_id into model `protected $fillable = ['role_id'];`

Comment: array:9 [▼
  "_token" => "bDuTwOZBmw3bNhFvme4Yk9n5KY8jau7H2H79QTXR"
  "name" => "Ad"
  "surname" => "fds"
  "role_id" => "1"
  "email" => "chazecka@gmail.com"
  "password" => "123456"
  "password_confirmation" => "123456"
  "workplace" => "52-100"
  "note" => "fsa"
]

Comment: as you can see, role_id is present

Comment: @kenken9999 fillable was the trick, I need a break. Thanks a lot bro.

Comment: @kenken9999  feel free to post and answer with something like: everytime you add a field, make sure to add it to fillable also. That is accepted answer.

Comment: when you use mass assignment.. make sure the value you want to store/update must be in fillable.. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

everytime you add a field, make sure to add it to fillable also

in model

```
protected $fillable = ['role_id'];
```